# Passing CSS sheet into theme setting of Stratus 2 Beta

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, soundcloud-stratus

I'm trying to customize my [Stratus 2 Beta](http://www.stratus.sc/#options) with a theme, and so I created a separate CSS file called "stratus.css" and placed that in my CSS folder of my website - with the CSS code being exactly the same as [this](http://www.stratus.sc/themes/dark.css).

Here's my JS:

```
jQuery('body').stratus({ 
    links: 'http://soundcloud.com/foofighters/sets/wasting-light',
    theme: 'css/stratus.css'
    /* theme: http://www.stratus.sc/themes/dark.css */
});
```

Now, everything works great, except for the theme, which seems to not at all be registering, instead inheriting the CSS properties of my website.

I tried adding

```
<link href = "css/stratus.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

to my HTML, in addition to the necessary scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stratus.sc/stratus.js"></script>
```

But none of this works.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: just tried loading your site and I see the following error: `GET http://www.stratus.sc/css/application.css 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Comment: It means that an error happened on your server and it failed to respond with the css file. I tried loading your site again and it looks like you changed something because the error is gone now.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't change anything, what does your Stratus look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the full HTTP path for your css file if you are able to do so.

```
jQuery('body').stratus({ 
    links: 'http://soundcloud.com/foofighters/sets/wasting-light',
    theme: 'http://www.yourdomain.com/css/stratus.css'
    /* theme: http://www.stratus.sc/themes/dark.css */
});
```

The stratus script uses `http://www.stratus.sc` as the root url and will in your case search for `http://www.stratus.sc/css/stratus.css` unless you enter the above.

Comment: What if I don't have a domain? How would I bypass this?

Comment: No, I'm not; that's the thing.

Comment: The stratus.js scripts sends the theme url to `http://stratus.sc/player` and thus if you give the theme a relative path it will be relative to `http://stratus.sc` and thus not find your local css/stratus.css. So to use your own css file it seems that you have bring it online so you can fetch it. If you can't setup a local server you should maybe look for someplace to host it.

Comment: A fast and easy way you can use until you have a server for your website is to host the css file on e.g. dropbox: http://docs.helpscout.net/article/92-stylesheet-dropbox